# Project Leaflet LatLng to tile pixel coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet

For canvas layers, how can I access the clicked pixel of a specific tile? Given a LatLng like `{ lat: 37.68816, lng: -119.76196 }`, how can I: #1, retrieve the correct tile clicked, and #2, the pixel coordinates within the tile? Both of these should consider `maxNativeZoom`.

Answer (score 8):

A CRS like `L.CRS.EPSG3857` is required. The map's CRS is accessible by `map.options.crs`. The true zoom, tile size (like 256, but could be 512 or higher about `maxNativeZoom`) and a pixel origin like `map.getPixelOrigin()` are required:

```
const latlngToTilePixel = (latlng, crs, zoom, tileSize, pixelOrigin) => {
    const layerPoint = crs.latLngToPoint(latlng, zoom).floor()
    const tile = layerPoint.divideBy(tileSize).floor()
    const tileCorner = tile.multiplyBy(tileSize).subtract(pixelOrigin)
    const tilePixel = layerPoint.subtract(pixelOrigin).subtract(tileCorner)

    return [tile, tilePixel]
}
```

First, convert the `latlng` to a layer point. Now all units are in pixels.

Second, divide by `tileSize` and round down. This gives the tile "slippy" coordinates.

Third, multiply back by `tileSize` to get the pixel coordinates of the tile corner, adjusted for `pixelOrigin`.

Finally, to get the tile pixels, subtract the layer point from origin and tile corner.

Comment: Also, do read the Leaflet tutorials, specifically the one about [extending Leaflet to create new layers](http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html). The concepts of pixel coordinates and pixel origin are explained there in length.