# Leaflet LatLng coordinates to xy map

Tags: leaflet, coordinates

How leaflet does to calculate the x y coordinates of the tiles from zoom z, latitude and longitude coordinates ?
what is the formula please?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Project Leaflet LatLng to tile pixel coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986573/project-leaflet-latlng-to-tile-pixel-coordinates)

Comment: The way that Leaflet works can be seen by inspecting the source code, starting from `L.GridLayer`'s `_update`, then `L.Map`'s `project, then `L.CRS`'s `latLngToPoint`, then `L.Projection.SphericalMercator`'s `project`. But I think that you are not really interested in *how* Leaflet does this, but in how to calculate this yoruself, so you should start by reading https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map.latlngtoContainerPoint(latlng)` but when you want the formular you can look into the `src`

[Leafet/Map.js#L1071](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/0d06c4256f4312a7122c23626c8bd36e14269d01/src/map/Map.js#L1071) --> [Leafet/Map.js#L1014](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/0d06c4256f4312a7122c23626c8bd36e14269d01/src/map/Map.js#L1014)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are referring to computation of tile z x y "coordinates" / names, then there is a very simple algorithm, as described on OpenStreetMap wiki about slippy maps: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

> Lon./lat. to tile numbers

```
n = 2 ^ zoom
xtile = n * ((lon_deg + 180) / 360)
ytile = n * (1 - arsinh(tan(lat_rad)) / π)) / 2
```

With arsinh being the [Inverse hyperbolic sine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions)

Some background explanation:

> - X goes from 0 (left edge is 180 °W) to 2<sup>zoom</sup> − 1 (right edge is 180 °E)
> - Y goes from 0 (top edge is 85.0511 °N) to 2<sup>zoom</sup> − 1 (bottom edge is 85.0511 °S) in a Mercator projection

See the wiki page for further explanation and details, as well as some code in different programming languages.